# SQL dynamically append numbers to records

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Using SQL Server 2012, I have the following data:

```
Reference      Value
---------------------
1              val
1              val
1              val
2              val
2              val
3              val
3              val
```

I need to append a number to Value as follows based on the number of unique references. This must only be done if there are different References in the list i.e. more than one unique one:

```
Reference      Value
---------------------
REF123         val 1
REF123         val 1
REF123         val 1
REF789         val 2
REF789         val 2
REF999         val 3
REF999         val 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT Reference, Value + CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Reference) FROM @t ) > 1 
                           THEN CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Reference) AS VARCHAR(20)) 
                           ELSE '' 
                          END
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated sub-query to count (distinct) reference values, this row and earlier.

```
select reference, value + ' ' + cast((select count(distinct t2.Reference)
                                      from tablename t2
                                      where t2.Reference <= t1.Reference) as varchar(11))
from tablename t1
```

A think `+` is SQL Server concat (ANSI SQL `||`), and `CAST` may be `CONVERT`...

Comment: Thanks, can you explain this line please - where t2.Reference <= t1.Reference

Comment: Count the sub-select's distinct rows with a reference value less or equal to the main-query's Reference value.

Comment: This doesn't cater for the scenario where there is only one unique reference - It will still label the value with a 1